# Can't Get Subclass Working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a subclass of asp:DropDownList so I can use asp:DdlNoEventValidation instead. This is so I can circumvent event validation.

Here's the page directive

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="NoValidationDropDownList" %>
```

and here's the class that is supposed to inherit the DropDownList (it's a seperate .cs file sitting App_Code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace System.Web.UI.WebControls
{
    public class DdlNoEventValidation : System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList
    {
    }
}
```

Here are the error's I'm getting

> Warning   1   Element 'DdlNoEventValidation' is not a known element. This
>   can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the
>   web.config file is missing.
>
> Error 2   Could not load file or assembly 'NoValidationDropDownList' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Error 3   Unknown server tag 'asp:DdlNoEventValidation'.

This should be simple and I'm obviously doing something very wrong despite trawling here and the rest of the Internet for an answer. This is driving me insane, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some references on how to do this (never use the same namespace from the framework itself when creating your own classes !):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbazwch5.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.toolboxdataattribute.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/232972/847363 (working sample code with a `DropDownList` subclass)

Comment: I have no idea how miss the above stackoverflow link - exactly what I wanted. All's working perfectly and my AJAX cascade dropdown is now working! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace as if it is your own in your custom code.

The controls in the Microsoft assembly are *signed* - yours are not (and even if they are, they wouldn't have the same signature, for obvious reasons).

So, using this namespace is not a good idea - use your own custom namespace for your control.