# C# ASP Add custom behavior to every System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I want to run some code every time an instance of System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button is clicked.

Is there a way I can drop this functionality into the default OnClick method for the button class, or will I have to make a new class that inherits from System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button?

For example everytime I click a button, I want the code

```
Debug.WriteLine ("hello world")
// other code here
```

to run,
but do not want to declare all that code in the OnClick method of every button on my page

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //when I get here, I want the code above to have run without having to paste it all into this method
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Another button, don't want to be duplicating all that code again
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating your own button that inherits from Button? You might be able to do that and then override as needed. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232934/subclassing-dropdownlist-in-asp-net/232972#232972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mike Cheel who confirmed that I do indeed need to make a new class to achieve this

```
public class MyButton : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("hello");
    }
}
```

which is then instantiated in the designer file

```
protected global::WebApplication7.MyButton Button1;
```

and in the cs file for the page I can add my button specific behaviour

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Goodbye");
}
```